# Does input readonly attribute works for text and textarea only?

Tags: html, xhtml, html-select, forms

Does input readonly attribute work for text/textarea?
If yes, why not it works for select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on both `input[type="text"]` and `textarea`

It's not meant to work with `select`, but if you want to prevent user of option selection I suggest using `disabled` attribute on each option.

Comment: Thanks. . Yes I know I can use disabled. . But that will let html form not include field values when form is submit. My question is to know the logic behind readonly attribute not available for other input type like select, radio, checkbox !

Comment: `readonly` only applies to textual input fields, it's only logical as there is two text usages - write and read.
You can use JavaScript to prevent selection of your listed input types.

Comment: Ant, try to use disabled on radio's 'wrong' answers and not on the right one. It will submit the value too then.

Checkboxes can be fixed by an hidden field after that.